# Firestore transaction fails on get and set of a document which once existed

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Given a simple transaction which calls `get` and then `set` for the same document reference in a transaction to a db where the document does not exist.

This is the code:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var docRef = db.collection("devtest").doc("doc-1");

return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
    return transaction.get(docRef).then((doc) => {
        transaction.set(docRef, {
            aValue: "hello world" }); }); });
```

Running this code in the browser against the emulator database works fine. Running again works again.

But when I (manually) delete the document from the database and then run the code again, it fails with:

```
FirebaseError: the stored version (1619370082687231) does not match the required base version (0)
    at new zr (http://localhost:50001/__/firebase/8.2.3/firebase-firestore.js:1:47931)
```

Reloading the browser page does not fix this issue. But restarting the emulator does - until the document gets deleted again.

Why is this?

This seams like a bug. There should be no difference in behavior, between a "document never existed" and "document existed and was deleted".

Comment: You might want to check if the document exists after your `.get`, using `if (!doc.exists) {return null;}`. If this works for you, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: But I want to do the `transaction.set(...` even if the doc does not exist.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please update it to show what the expected flow should be if there is an existing document and if there isn't an existing document

Comment: I don't care about the behavior. I just think it should be the same behavior when the document never existed and when the document existed and was deleted.

Comment: I'm facing the same exact issue, any updates to this problem? @Witek

Answer (score -1):

The transaction will only succeed if there is a document to `get`.  If you want to update the document if it exists and set it if it doesn't, try using the `catch` block to set the document, if it doesn't already exist.  You may also want to add some error handling in here, just in case the error isn't related to a document which doesn't yet exist

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var docRef = db.doc("devtest/doc-1");

return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
  return transaction.get(docRef)
  .then((doc) => {
    transaction.set(docRef, {aValue: "hello world"});
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    transaction.set(docRef, {aValue: "hello world"});
  });
});
```